# awk, if else statment, assigning conditions to arrays

Tags: awk

If I have a file where in the first column is a set of words:

```
 sad
 dog
 hand
 paper
 computer
 rabbit
 cow
```

and I want to get the word length of the column, check if it's even or odd, and if even assign it to an array and if odd, assign to to a separate array.

This is what I have and it is wrong at far as I know at least in the syntax:

`awk '{if (print length($1)%2 = 0 ) x[NR]=$1; else  y[NR]=$1;}'`

Comment: The `print` is incorrect. Also `=` is assignment not comparison. Use `==`.

Comment: is there a way to go about checking everything in the array, so in a way of printing everything stored in the arrays?  Also, thank you!

Comment: You can certainly loop over the arrays and do what you want with the entries. If you describe your actual goal in the question you'll get more useful help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might be your starting point:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if (length($0)%2) {
        odd[++numOdd] = $0
    }
    else {
        even[++numEven] = $0
    }
}
END {
    for (i=1; i<=numOdd; i++) {
        print "ODD:", odd[i]
    }
    for (i=1; i<=numEven; i++) {
        print "EVEN:", even[i]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
ODD: sad
ODD: dog
ODD: paper
ODD: cow
EVEN: hand
EVEN: computer
EVEN: rabbit
```

but you may be going in 100% the wrong direction with whatever problem it is you are trying to solve so I'd recommend you edit your question to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
awk '{if (length($1)%2) odd[NR]=$1; else even[NR]=$1}'
```

but, perhaps that's not what you need to do.